# What happens to a repo's fork when its visibility is changed?

Tags: github

I just want to know what happens to a forked repo if the visibility of the main repo changed from public to private? Also, tell me what happens if the visibility of the repo again changed to public.

Answer (score 0):

If a public repository is made private, its public forks are split off into a new network. As with deleting a public repository, one of the existing public forks is chosen to be the new parent repository and all other repositories are forked off of this new parent. Subsequent pull requests go to this new parent.

In other words, a public repository's forks will remain public in their own separate repository network even after the parent repository is made private.

[Source](https://docs.github.com/en/pull-requests/collaborating-with-pull-requests/working-with-forks/what-happens-to-forks-when-a-repository-is-deleted-or-changes-visibility)

Comment: And what if it is made public again